# Where to host my 4 asp.net websites - recommendations needed

Tags: hosting, asp.net

I have 4 asp.net websites that use sql server 2008. 
I need some recommendations for hosting my sites.

Each of them have at least one subdomain, I am running one web-service, and in some cases one windows service for each of them (and perhaps going to host dotnet facebook app).

I would like to host them all at the same place.
I have tried discountasp but it is too expensive and difficult when you have many domains and some subdomains.

I have been thinking about VSP (appliedi dot net or godaddy dot com)
but the problem with those are limited ip addresses and also RAM included (Max 768MB Guaranteed).
But I like to be able to connect to them with remote desktop connection.

I have also been looking into Grid hosting at GoDaddy:
https://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/hosting/grid.asp?ci=13633
But not sure if there is anything there that stops me from using it.
Also not sure how it is working and how it is different from VSP.

Currently I am running all those sites on my own server with 4GB of memory and 500 GB disk space. 
But that is a big risk - server goes down once in a while and so on.

(Stupid system - I cant add three links cause I dont have some points needed)

Comment: The system is to prevent linkspam.  Generally, if you include the addresses you want to link to, someone will come by and edit them to become links once vetted.

Comment: This has been asked several times ... http://serverfault.com/search?q=asp.net+hosting

Comment: I have read all of the answers to other questions and they don't answer my questions.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to give [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com) a look. Hostnames are configured by you, and we don't currently charge extra for adding additional domains.

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)

Comment: While providing answers to unanswered questions is appropriated, this does tend to come over quite spammy, plus the questions is over two years old so it is likely the OP has found a solution by now.